# how to calculate sum of hours decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you guys help me to get sum of hours in decimal. i really don't know how to ask properly.

The sum 7.6 should be 8 hours because my data is 0.1 hour until 0.5 hours. Can you guys help me to get the sum without getting sum that is *.6 until *.9?

```
function change() {
       var h1 = $('#hs1').val();
       var h2 = $('#hs2').val();
       var h3 = $('#hs3').val();
       var h4 = $('#hs4').val();
       var sum = parseFloat(h1) + parseFloat(h2)  + parseFloat(h3) + parseFloat(h4);
       document.getElementById("the_sum").innerHTML = parseFloat(sum).toFixed(1);
    }
```

here is my code to calculate sum in the drop down on change.

i actually want the decimal. but i dont want it to be 0.6 just until 0.5 because im calculating hours in decimal. $hour_arr = array(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,3,3.1,3.2,‌​3.3,3.4,3.5,4,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5,5,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,6,6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,7,7‌​.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,8);

for example 0.1+0.2+0.3 = 0.6 this is hours. 0.6 supposed to be 1 hours. not 0.6. and 0.7 should be 1.1 hours. you guys understand my problem?

i want to get 0.1 hour + 0.2 hour + 0.3 hour = 1 hour. not 0.6 hours. help me guys

Comment: Hi! What exactly is the problem? I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why is there PHP on this question? It seems you are trying to solve this calcluation entirely in the frontend. What kind of values do you get in your `h*`-variables? What is the problem you are facing with your sum-calculation?

Comment: I wanna get sum of the value in my drop down box. whenever user click the drop down box. it will detect its value and calculate its sum. i already get that done. but the values in my drop down box is hours. for example 0.1 hours is for 10 minutes. 0.5 hours is for 50 minutes. and 1 hours is for 60 minutes. the problem comes when user pick the first box 0.1 hours, the second box 0.2 hours, the third box 0.3 hours. the sum is 0.6 hours. 0.6 hours should be 1 hours. how to calculate the value so that i can shows only 0.1-0.5 then 1 hours?

Comment: just write `toFixed(0);`

Comment: h* is string value from my drop down box. there is 4 drop down box

Comment: i actually want the decimal. but i dont want it to be 0.6 just until 0.5 because im calculating hours in decimal. $hour_arr = array(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,4,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5,5,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,6,6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,7,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,8);

Comment: `if ((sum - Math.floor(sum)) > 0.5 ) sum = Math.floor(sum) + 1;`

Comment: Argh, you're making life difficult for yourself by using 0.1 == 10 minutes, etc. you'd be better off using 10, 20, 30 etc. as labels in your dropdowns  but using 10/60, 20/60, 30/60, etc. as your values. At least you'd be able to add them up easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is another try:

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/fzyxfbfz/3/

HTML:

```
<select id="hs1">
</select>
<select id="hs2">
</select>
<select id="hs3">
</select>
<select id="hs4">
</select>

<div id="the_sum"></div>
```

JS:

```
//This is just to populate the select boxes with values from 0 to 8
var arrData = new Array();
for(i=0;i<=8;i+=0.1) {
 arrData.push(i.toFixed(1));   
}
$('#hs1, #hs2, #hs3, #hs4').each(function() {
    for(i=0;i<arrData.length;i++) {
      $(this).append('<option value="' + arrData[i] + '">' + arrData[i] + '</option>');   
    }
});

$('#hs1, #hs2, #hs3, #hs4').change(function() {
    var h1 = $('#hs1').val();
    var h2 = $('#hs2').val();
    var h3 = $('#hs3').val();
    var h4 = $('#hs4').val();

    //Calculate the sum
    var sum = parseFloat(h1) + parseFloat(h2)  + parseFloat(h3) + parseFloat(h4);
    sum = parseFloat(sum).toFixed(1);
    var parts = sum.split('.');

    parts[1] = parseFloat(parts[1]);
    parts[0] = parseFloat(parts[0]);
    if(parts[1] >= 6) {
     parts[1] -= 6;
     parts[0] += 1;
    }
    $("#the_sum").html(parts.join('.'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   document.getElementById("the_sum").innerHTML = Math.ceil(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is display the selected time in hours as a float?

So

```
20min + 20min + 20min = 1.0
30min + 20min + 30min = 1.333333
```

You should use the minutes as value of the select boxes and just divide the sum by 60 to get the float number:

HTML:

```
<select id="hs1" onchange="change()">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<select id="hs2" onchange="change()">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<select id="hs3" onchange="change()">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<select id="hs4" onchange="change()">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
</select>

<div id="the_sum"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#hs1, #hs2, #hs3, #hs4').change(function() {
    var h1 = $('#hs1').val();
    var h2 = $('#hs2').val();
    var h3 = $('#hs3').val();
    var h4 = $('#hs4').val();
    var sum = parseFloat(h1) + parseFloat(h2)  + parseFloat(h3) + parseFloat(h4);
    $("#the_sum").html(parseFloat(sum / 60).toFixed(1));
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/fzyxfbfz/

Comment: the value of my drop down box is in array. all 4 dropdown box is like this.$hour_arr = array(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,3,3.1,3.2,‌​3.3,3.4,3.5,4,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5,5,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,6,6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,7,7‌​.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,8);

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for you 7.9 its 8 hours and 30 minutes... so use this

```
sum = sum.toString().split(".");
console.log(sum);
sum = parseFloat(sum[0]) + parseFloat( parseInt(sum[1])>6 ? 1+(parseInt(sum[1])-6)/10 : sum[1] );
```

then you can split again to get separated hours and minute

https://jsfiddle.net/62yv7dt0/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change', updateSum);
});

function updateSum(){
  var hours = 0,
      sum = 0;
  $('select option:selected').each(function(i, option){
    sum += parseInt($(option).val());
  });
  var hours = sum / 60.0;
  
  $('#sum').text(sum + ' minutes = ' + hours + ' hours');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='hs1'>
  <option value='0'>Select</option>
  <option value='10'>10 minutes</option>
  <option value='20'>20 minutes</option>
  <option value='30'>30 minutes</option>
  <option value='40'>40 minutes</option>
  <option value='50'>50 minutes</option>
  <option value='60'>1 hour</option>
</select>

<select id='hs3'>
  <option value='0'>Select</option>
  <option value='10'>10 minutes</option>
  <option value='20'>20 minutes</option>
  <option value='30'>30 minutes</option>
  <option value='40'>40 minutes</option>
  <option value='50'>50 minutes</option>
  <option value='60'>1 hour</option>
</select>

<select id='hs3'>
  <option value='0'>Select</option>
  <option value='10'>10 minutes</option>
  <option value='20'>20 minutes</option>
  <option value='30'>30 minutes</option>
  <option value='40'>40 minutes</option>
  <option value='50'>50 minutes</option>
  <option value='60'>1 hour</option>
</select>

<select id='hs4'>
  <option value='0'>Select</option>
  <option value='10'>10 minutes</option>
  <option value='20'>20 minutes</option>
  <option value='30'>30 minutes</option>
  <option value='40'>40 minutes</option>
  <option value='50'>50 minutes</option>
  <option value='60'>1 hour</option>
</select>

<div>Sum: <span id='sum'></span></div>
```